# Adding XML to a column with MySQL LOAD_FILE()

Tags: php, mysql

I want to load an xml file into a table column with MySQL. How do I do this with an INSERT statement instead of an UPDATE statement?

This code does an INSERT to create a new row, gets the id for the last inserted row, then attempts to do the update to load the xml file.  But it doesn't update the row with the xml info.

I would like to know what to fix to put the xml in the database column.  I also want to streamline the code and do the LOAD_FILE in one INSERT statement.

MySQL database table structure

```
Field         Datatype       Attributes            Extra

userid        INT(6)         unsigned              auto_increment
user_events   LONGTEXT
```

PHP code to add xml file

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$con = mysql_connect("hostname","adminuser","adminpassword");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("test_db", $con);

$qinsert = "INSERT INTO load_xml (`user_events`) VALUES ('user events')";
$result_insert = mysql_query($qinsert);

$qtext = "SELECT * FROM load_xml";
$result = mysql_query($qtext);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows ( $result );

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo 'user id '.$row[0].' user_events '.$row[1].'<br/>';
}

$insert_id = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";
$rin_id = mysql_query($insert_id);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($rin_id);
$userid = $row[0];
echo 'last added id '.$userid.'<br/>';

$update_xml = "UPDATE load_xml SET user_events=LOAD_FILE('my_events.xml') WHERE userid='$userid'";
$result_update = mysql_query($update_xml);

$qtext = "SELECT * FROM load_xml";
$result = mysql_query($qtext);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows ( $result );

echo $numrows.'<br/>';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {

    echo 'user_id '.$row[0].' user_events '.$row[1].'<br/>';

}

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the file in the original insert. The file path is that of a file on the server. The mysql user used to connect must have the file privilege. It must be the full path. On windows you need to replace back slashes with forward slashes -

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$con = mysql_connect("hostname","adminuser","adminpassword");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("test_db", $con);

$qinsert = "INSERT INTO load_xml (`user_events`) VALUES (LOAD_FILE('/full/path/to/my_events.xml'))";
$result_insert = mysql_query($qinsert);

$userid = mysql_insert_id();
echo 'last added id '.$userid.'<br/>';

$qtext = "SELECT * FROM load_xml";
$result = mysql_query($qtext);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows ( $result );

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo 'user id '.$row[0].' user_events '.$row[1].'<br/>';
}

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

**UPDATE** - here is another version using [PDO prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) -

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test_db;host=hostname', 'adminuser', 'adminpassword');

$qinsert = "INSERT INTO load_xml (`user_events`) VALUES (?)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($qinsert);

$stmt->execute(array(file_get_contents('my_events.xml')));

?>
```

Comment: So I should not assume that mysql_query will look in the current directory.  Is there a way in php to determine the current directory and build the path with it?

Comment: LOAD_FILE is a server side (mysql server) action and needs to be able to access the file. You can use `$path = dirname(__FILE__);` to get the path to the current file. You might be better off using `file_get_contents()` to load the data into a string and then pass that into your query. I have added another example to my answer.

Comment: The PDO prepared statement approach worked very well!  Thanks.